# kinematics - is the question wrong or? A hiker has a displacement

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A hiker has a displacement s km, at a time $t$ hours, modeled by $$s= t^3 -4t$$

$t$ is bigger than or equal to $1$.

- Find the maximum displacement from the starting point:

For this one, I got the answer but I think it should be minimum? There isn't a maximum really?

- Find the maximum speed of the hiker

I got $4m$ per hour for this one. I differentiated the displacement formula and differentiate it again, equate it to $0$ to find the maximum. But it says finding the speed, I actually found the velocity. (But are they different in this sense?)

I don't know...

Comment: What is a "displacement ski"?

Comment: oh sorry, s km...

Comment: What is your source?

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, it must be minimum. Only minimum. Check the graph
    https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+t%5E3+-+4t

2) To get the velocity curve, you need to differentiate the displacement    curve. And you have equated velocity curve 6t to zero(6t=0) and got t=0.
But remember from question that t>1. How did you end up with 4 m/hr ?? 
And more over the speed also doesn't have finite maximum value. You can see that from [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%203*(t%5E2)%20-%204)

Comment: exactly. I am so confused. The question is weird..